# Removal of repeated characters up to new character with regular expression

Tags: regex, replace

I’m trying to write a RegExp in JavaScript that removes all repeated characters from a string up to the point there is a new character.

at the moment I have:

```
'mmoooovvvemmmeeent'.replace(/.*m/,'')
```

This returns `ent` but I’d like it to return `oooovvvemmmeeent`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anchor `^` or a word boundary `\b`, then repeat 1+ times the `m` char and replace with an empty string

```
\bm+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovVfJP/1)

```js
console.log("mmoooovvvemmmeeent".replace(/\bm+/, ''));
```

Comment: That’s brilliant, works perfectly. Need to spend some time learning RegExp!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to give you `oooovvvemmmeeent`

```js
console.log(
  'mmoooovvvemmmeeent'.replace(/(.)\1+/, '')
) // oooovvvemmmeeent
```

- `(.)` - capture one character as a group
- `\1` - expect that same character again ("backreference to group 1")
- `+` - one or more
- `''` - then replace that with an empty string

But if instead you actually need `movement`, then this will do it for you:

```js
console.log(
  'mmoooovvvemmmeeent'.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1')
) // movement
```

- `(.)\1+` - capture repeated characters
- `g` - all of them
- `'$1'` - replace with capture group 1, which is the repeated character